# Why is 2:1 ratio of EPA:DHA recommended

Tags: supplement, ratio, epa-eicosapentaenoic-acid, dha-docosahexaenoic-acid

I frequently see it recommended that EPA and DHA be taken in a 2:1 ratio.

What primary sources (i.e. clinical trials, peer-reviewed studies, etc.) justify this specific ratio? What is the justification?